# API Call in Xamarin with API Key

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm trying to make a call to API in Xamarin (C#)

HttpResponse could not be found

I've tried two different methods of making this call.
1st time no API key could be found (I don't know where to place it within the call)

API Call Attempt #1

```
        private async void GetProduct()
        {
            // Url which is used for making the get request
            string url = "https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com/food/ingredients/substitutes?ingredientName=butter";
            //Creating a Http client
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            // Making the request and putting the response into responce
            string response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
            // Parsing the data using NewtonJson package
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SubstituteRootObject>(response);
        }
```

API Call Attempt #2

```
        static async Task<SubstituteRootObject> GetRootInfo() {
            HttpResponse<SubstituteRootObject> response = await Unirest.get("https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com/food/ingredients/substitutes?ingredientName=butter")
            .header("X-RapidAPI-Host", "spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com")
            .header("X-RapidAPI-Key", apiKey)
            .asJson();
            return response.Body;
        }
```

I want to be able to make a call to this API and return a JSON result and bind the values to a ListView, Label etc.

```
        public class Substitute
        {
            public string __invalid_name__0 { get; set; }
        }

        public class SubstituteRootObject
        {
            public string status { get; set; }
            public string ingredient { get; set; }
            public List<Substitute> substitutes { get; set; }
            public string message { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: What is the problem with attempt #2?  Does it compile?  Throw a runtime exception?  How you pass the API key is completely dependent on the requirements of the API provider - there is no universal answer for this we can give you.

Comment: @Jason the type or namespace 'HttpResonpse' could not be found

Comment: looking at the Unirest git repo, HttpResponse<T> is in unirest_net.http namespace

Comment: Then you either need to look at the docs for this `Unirest` library or fix the first snippet by adding the custom headers (e.g. `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-RapidAPI-Key", apiKey);`

Comment: I've added  (e.g. client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-RapidAPI-Key", apiKey); custom headers. Getting this error now 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).'

Comment: authentication is failing.  I'd double check your API key

Comment: @Jason I had host in API key , and API key in host by mistake, switched around and it worked! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should add headers like this.

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-rapidapi-key", api-key);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-rapidapi-host", "");
```

And make sure to add Subscribe to an API on RapidAPI Hub; otherwise, you'll get a 401 status code.